# Win10 How to disable screen autorotation (programmaticaly or in a batch command)

Tags: c#, windows, c++-cli, registry, windows-10

I´m writing a Windows 10 application using C++/CLI. The application is going to run on a portable computer (that runs standard Win10 SO, not the tablet version).

This portable computer has autorotation, but I need to keep my application only in Portrait configuration.

I want to disable screen autorotation when the application comes up. Is there a C++/CLI command, a C# command or a batch command that I can do it programatically (the batch would be called from my app) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regini.exe`, with a parameter file specifying the key to set:

AutorotateOff.reg:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation
    Enable = REG_DWORD 0DWORD`

Command to issue on command line with elevated right:
`c:\>regini AutorotateOff.reg`

<s>Been a while, but this should do the job:</s>

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation", true);

if(regKey != null)
{
   regKey.SetValue("Enable", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
   regKey.Close();
}
```

Comment: This will change the setting at the system level, and needs admin privileges. I don't think it's what the asker expects. Also, backslashes need to be escaped, or you need to use a verbatim (C#) or raw (C++/CLI) string.

Comment: You are right, the code above has to be wrapped before use.